# Azure Data Factory copy activity failed with Exception ERROR [22007] Timestamp is not recognized?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, azure-data-factory, data-transfer

I am using Azure Data Factory to copy data from CSV to Snowflake, the copy executes fine but it has an error when it comes to copy **Date** from the CSV which has this value (14/01/2000), if the **Date** is (12/10/2000) or less, it works very well.

Here is the error message:

> ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [22007] Timestamp ‘14/01/2000’ is not recognized

[image]

I tried to adjust the format of the date in the copy activity to be dd/MM/yyyy or change the Culture to en-UK as the below image but it has the same issue.

[image]

I tried to use all the possible types of date in Snowflake as below but I still have the same issue:

- DATE
- DATETIME
- TIMESTAMP
- TIMESTAMP_LTZ

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake doesn't supports format as DD/MM/YYYY and even it supports MM/DD/YYYY it can lead to incorrect dates (05/02/2013 could be interpreted as May 2, 2013 instead of February 5, 2013).

So this:

```
select '14/01/2000'::timestamp;
```

produces:

```
Timestamp '14/01/2000' is not recognized
```

while this:

```
select '01/14/2000'::timestamp;
```

produces:

```
2000-01-14 00:00:00.000
```

Same for:

```
select '14/01/2000'::date; 
select '01/14/2000'::date;
```

The guidelines for how to use date/timestamp formats are described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html).

In your case one way to get that value as a date is to use the **to_date** function, like this:

```
select to_date('14/01/2000', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

gives me:

```
2000-01-14
```

Comment: @Seriu thanks, while you answer is really valuable but it doesn't solve my issue.
How can I transfer the date from the CSV? Or what I need to do to solve the issue?

Comment: @Mohamed.Radwan-MVP I've added to the answer the function to_date which can be used in your case to transform the input date you have in your CSV.

Comment: ,unfortunately, I can't call any function in the copy activity for Azure Data Factory.

Comment: How does your COPY INTO looks like? Can't you do something like **COPY INTO <table>(col1, col2,...,coln) FROM (SELECT $1, TO_DATE($2, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), ..., $n) FROM ...**

Comment: No, I can't do that, I copy from one system (Azure Storage account) to another system (Snowflake) and this copy run by integration runtime which is different from the source and destination execution